# declare a vector that contains the class itself in the class definition

Tags: c++

In c++, We all know that this code is wrong:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node node;
};
```

However, declaring a vector like this is right, WHY?

```
class Node {
    public:
        std::vector<Node> nodeVec;
};
```

Comment: It isn't right, it is actually undefined behaviour (whether is thould be this way or not is a different matter.) Boost has [some containers that allow you to do this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types).

Comment: @juanchopanza Why isn't it right? Nodes are added to the vector dynamically. There's no infinite recursion here.

Comment: @NeilKirk No idea why, but the standard says so. IIRC there has been discussion about removing this restriction. I don't know what the status of that is.

Comment: It seems that [this site](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814) explain it, although I don't understand it..

Comment: To address the logical issue; the first one can never work as it is infinite descent of Nodes. However in the second one, so long as the default constructor makes `nodeVec` empty there is no infinite descent.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine in the C++14 compiler I'm using. And it provides a very convenient pattern for representing an arbitrarily large complex tree-shaped data structure inside a “single” instance. A nice property is that all storage management for the entire tree is handled automatically by `std::vector`. For example you can have a `Node` member variable in a class `Foo` and not worry about deleting the tree when you are done with the enclosing `Foo` instance.

As described elsewhere ([How can I declare a member vector of the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913578/how-can-i-declare-a-member-vector-of-the-same-class)) it is not a problem for the compiler because the size of `std::vector<Node>` itself is independent of the size of `Node`, because `std::vector` is a fixed size header with a pointer to a separate block of managed storage on the heap.