# Refactoring out template of incomplete type for visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc

I wrote some code for an assignment that compiled and behaved as expected in gcc, but throws out C2027 'use of undefined type' when compiled in visual studio. Here's the behaviour that caused the error:

```
template<class Object>
class Foo{

public:
[....]

private: 
[....]

std::stack<Foo> bar;//error c2027 from instantiation with incomplete type
};
```

I understand why the error is happening, what I've been struggling to figure out is how to resolve the error without massively changing the structure of the code, or if that's even possible. In this particular case, the class was using the internal data structure of itself to store a copy of previous states it could be rolled back to.

Comment: @user463035818 Hum.  [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OPlkbTRmSI49JCgR) rejects the code so I'm going to say this is a gcc extension, and not actually valid standard C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a level of indirection:

```
struct FooData { /*...*/ };

struct Foo  {
    std::stack<FooData> bar;
};
```

For why your code compiles see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913578/how-can-i-declare-a-member-vector-of-the-same-class). In summary: Only some containers allow incomplete types as value_type (since C++17) for the others it is undefined behaviour (ie no diagnostics required). Thanks to NathanOliver for the link!

Comment: The code does compile with `-pedantic` with gcc.  Your example had the wrong class name: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZQJ4rAc4s9ULHmUY

Comment: Looks like this might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913578/how-can-i-declare-a-member-vector-of-the-same-class.  It's UB and only certain containers can use an incomplete type as the template parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver I couldnt find any gcc version that does not compile it (even with c++98) While clang seems to be always report an error